# Record video from HTML using NGINX and RTMP protocol

Tags: html, nginx

I would like to build up an application web with Streaming. I have been using HTML5 and PHP.

For other project, I have been using NGINX server, so I use `Open Broadcaster Software` to encode and to transmit my stream to NGINX server, so later I show it with a javascript and Flash in a html page. I have been using RTMP protocol with the direction of my server and so on...

So my problem is that I want to record video on a HTML5 page instead of using `Open Broadcaster Software`. In that way I can record it from HTML5, and watch it in another HTML5 page (using NGINX and RTMP)

Thanks so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Live Stream</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<h1 align="center">Live Stream</h1> 

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container clearfix">
<script type="text/javascript" src='jwplayer.js'></script>
    <div id='player_1'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('player_1').setup({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    stretching: "fill",
    primary: "flash",
    autostart: "true",
    sources:
 [
 {file: "rtmp://server:port/live/test"}
 ]
  });
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the way i recieve the streaming. I want the same way to capture and send it to a server.

So i want capture video and sound with HTML5 and create a FMS URL and to set a stream key in order to send it to NGINX. But i dont know if its possible to do that...

Thanks :)

Comment: please show the code that have tried.

Comment: Doing this "with HTML5" implies using `getUserMedia` and WebRTC streaming. With this you can either do direct P2P streaming between two clients, or you'll need a WebRTC capable media streaming/recording/broadcasting server. Have you investigated this at all? This is a bit of a broad topic...